# WebSecurityConfig устарел?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Делаю сайт на Spring Boot и руки дошли до авторизации пользователей.

Посмотрел разные статьи и узнал, что WebSecurityConfig устарел.

Каким способом лучше делать авторизацию?

Comment: если вы про WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter , то смотрите, к примеру, сюда: https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/fix-websecurityconfigureradapter-deprecated Если не про него, то уточняйте вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Авторизацию лучше конечно делать на новой версий а именно на `3.1.3`. Однако есть и другой способ , просто понизить версию Spring до `2.6.15` там `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` является основным классом для конфигурации безопасности и не является устаревшим. Также рекомендую использовать модули Spring одной версий что бы не было конфликтов. Для этого просто можете добавить `spring-boot-starter-parent` в проект и далее просто указывать зависимости без версий. Таким образом вы избежите конфликтов

```xml
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.15</version>
  </parent>
```